# Observing changes to an aurelia array when using value converters

Tags: aurelia

I'm attempting to create a customElement in Aurelia which is a table that can be filtered, sorted and paged.

I'm using Value Converters in to do this as so:

```
<tr repeat.for="item of tableModel | filter:searchTerm:filterFunc | sort: { propertyName: sortProperty, direction: sortDirection } | pager: { index: pagerIndex, numberToShow: pagerAmount }">

@bindable tableModel;
bind() {
  this.pagerIndex = 0;
  this.pagerAmount = 10;
  this.pagerTotal = this.tableModel.length / this.pagerAmount;
}
```

To work out how many pages there are I used the current tableModel length divided by a value set on bind().

The pagination works fine until you filter as the tableModel length isn't updated.

Is there a way to keep track of the length of the array after it's been filtered by the value converter and then use this to update the pagination?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do that. If you're sorting over an existing array, and filtering an existing array then the pagination should just respect that!

Comment: The paging works as in it displays the correct number of items and will page forward the correct amount. The problem comes from having a 'last' button. As it uses tableModel to work out how many pages there are, this doesn't get updated when the pager value converter is run.

Comment: It should all be driven from the array that is being mutated by the filtering and sorting.

Comment: I don't think value converters mutate the original array themselves. Perhaps I shouldn't be using value converters for this.

Comment: maybe not. You should clone the array passed to you and use that.